# How to use New-AzConfigurationAssignment Powershell cmdlet for Dynamic Scope for different subscriptions -Azure update manager

Tags: azure, powershell, patch, azure-virtual-machine, azure-update-management-center

I'm failing to set up Dynamic Scopes for my Maintenance Configuration related to VMs (InGuestPatching) with Powershell. I have created a maintenance configuration. Now I want to do the configuration assignment on number of virtual machines at scale using powershell over subscription level dynamic scope. But powershell cmdlet is failing to do so.

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Compute
Import-Module Az.Automation
Import-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.KeyVault
Import-Module Az.Maintenance
Import-Module Az.Compute  

Set-AzContext -Subscription ""

$maintenanceconfig =  New-AzMaintenanceConfiguration -ResourceGroup $RGName -Name $configName -MaintenanceScope $scope -Location $location -StartDateTime $startDateTime -TimeZone $timeZone -Duration $duration -RecurEvery $recurEvery -WindowParameterClassificationToInclude $WindowsParameterClassificationToInclude -InstallPatchRebootSetting $RebootOption -ExtensionProperty @{"InGuestPatchMode"="User"}     

New-AzConfigurationAssignment -ConfigurationAssignmentName $maintenanceconfig.Name -MaintenanceConfigurationId $maintenanceconfig.Id -ProviderName Microsoft.Compute -ResourceType virtualMachines -FilterLocation eastus2 -FilterOsType Windows -FilterOperator "Any" -FilterTag '{"network_environment" : ["sb"]}'
```

The above code is failing to create dynamic scope assignment and below is the error I am getting.

**Error**:

[image]

I don't know what exactly am I missing but this cmdlet is not working for me and MS documentation is lacking the information. Please suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use New-AzConfigurationAssignment Powershell cmdlet for Dynamic Scope for different subscriptions -Azure update manager.

Here is the updated **PowerShell** script for creating a maintenance configuration for a **VM**.

```
    $RGName           = "RG-Name"
    $configName        = "workervmscentralus"
    $scope            = "InGuestPatch"
    $location         = "eastus2euap"
    $startDateTime    = "2024-03-09 12:30"
    $timeZone         = "UTC"
    $duration         = "3:00"
    $recurEvery       = "Day"
    $WindowsParameterClassificationToInclud = "apt","httpd"
    $RebootOption = "IfRequired"
    $Flocation  =  "eastus2euap,centraluseuap"
    $maintenanceconfig = New-AzMaintenanceConfiguration -ResourceGroupName v-nehrujir-Mindtree `
    -Name workervmseastus `
    -MaintenanceScope "InGuestPatch" `
    -Location eastus2 `
    -Timezone "UTC" `
    -StartDateTime "2025-10-09 12:30" `
    -Duration "3:00" `
    -RecurEvery "Day" `
    -LinuxParameterPackageNameMaskToInclude "apt","httpd" `
    -ExtensionProperty @{inGuestPatchMode="User"} `
    -InstallPatchRebootSetting "IfRequired" `
    
    
  $assignment = New-AzConfigurationAssignment -ResourceGroup $RGName -ResourceName "testvm" -ConfigurationAssignmentName $maintenanceconfig.Name -MaintenanceConfigurationId $maintenanceconfig.Id -ProviderName Microsoft.Compute -ResourceType virtualMachines -FilterLocation eastus2  -FilterOsType Windows -FilterOperator "Any" -FilterTag '{"network_environment" : ["sb"]}' -Location centralus
    
 $assignment = New-AzConfigurationAssignment -ResourceGroup $RGName -ResourceName testvm -ConfigurationAssignmentName $maintenanceconfig.Name -MaintenanceConfigurationId $maintenanceconfig.Id -ProviderName Microsoft.Compute -ResourceType virtualMachines -FilterLocation eastus2 -FilterOsType Windows -FilterOperator "Any" -FilterTag '{"network_environment" : ["sb"]}' -Location centralus
```

To add **dynamic scope** into `multiple subscription` based filters, you can use the following code.

```
    $subscriptionnames = Get-AzSubscription | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    foreach ($subscriptionname in $subscriptionnames) {
        Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionname
        az maintenance assignment create-or-update-subscription --maintenance-configuration-id $maintenanceconfig.Id --subscription $subscriptionname --name $maintenanceconfig.Name --filter-locations centralus westus2 --filter-os-types windows linux --filter-tags '{"azsecpack":["nonprod"], "Department":["IT"]}' --filter-tags-operator All
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

After executing the script, the dynamic scope has been created in `Maintenance configuration`.

[image]
**Reference:** [az maintenance assignment create-or-update-subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/maintenance/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-maintenance-assignment-create-or-update-subscription)

Comment: I want to implement this for multiple VMs  using dynamic scope.
I am trying to setup dynamic scopes (multiple subscriptions filtering on a specific tag value) to a new maintenance configuration in Azure Update Manager. It can be done through the portal, but I need to be able to do it via Azure PowerShell script because these need to be created on a mass scale.

The New-AzConfigurationAssignment cmdlet is supposed to be able to setup dynamic scopes, but it doesn't seem to be able to do this by subscriptions. Is this possible or is there another cmdlet used to do this? @Venkat V

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic scope? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/update-manager/manage-dynamic-scoping?tabs=avms%2Cvm
For reference, this the MS doc. By dynamic scope I mean that the maintenance configuration can associate group of virtual machine for multiple subscriptions in a single assignment using filter option in "New-AzConfigurationAssignment" @Venkat V

Comment: Hi @Srishtigarg, I have updated answer as per requirement, kindly check and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: azure cli will work in powershell script if I try this locally from windows powershell ISE?

Comment: Yes, Kindly check and confirm the result.

Comment: `az : ERROR: 'maintenance' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
At C:\Users\srgarg\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1:27 char:1
+ az maintenance assignment create-or-update-subscription --maintenance ...`
I am getting above error after running this script. Can you please help me with this. @Venkat V

Comment: Check your CLI Version, it may require 2.51.0 or higher version. for more details follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/maintenance/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-maintenance-assignment-create-or-update-subscription) here.

Comment: I have updated it to 2.58. Idk what am I missing? I am running this code in powershell ISE.

Comment: Do I need to use importing libraries for azure cli @Venkat V

Comment: Still your facing same Error: 'maintenance' is misspelled or not recognized by the system?

Comment: Kindly close and reopen the PowerShell ISE, then check the same result again and also verify the az cli version by using az --version.

Comment: Yes, I am getting same issue

Comment: Can you please share your **Azure CLI Version**?

Comment: `azure-cli                         2.58.0

core                              2.58.0
telemetry                          1.1.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.26.0
azure-mgmt-resource             23.1.0b2

Python location 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\srgarg\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.`

Comment: Check whether the maintenance extension is available using the cmdlet:az extension list-available, if not installed, you can install using the cmdlet:  az extension add --name maintenance : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview

Comment: If still encounter any problems while executing the script, you may try to run it in **Azure Cloud Shell**

Comment: Ok sure! Thankyou so much @Venkat V. This helped me a lot. I think there is some policies in my pc which is restricting me to install this maintenance extension. I will try to fix it.